# Using node-imap, how do i move emails into another folder?

Tags: node.js, imap, node-imap

I have been trying to use node-imap to move emails from my inbox into a folder i created called "processed". But whenever i run my code, a random number of emails were moved. Those emails that were not moved throws this error:

```
Error: Error in IMAP command MOVE: Invalid messageset (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
```

When i run my code again, a random number of those emails that previously were unable to move were moved and others throw the same error. Running my code a few more times after that eventually moved all the emails to my "processed" folder.

I have no idea why certain emails could not be moved on the first run and unable to find any resources about "Error in IMAP command MOVE: Invalid messageset". There were many resources about IMAP command FETCH but I couldn't find any about IMAP command MOVE.

My code is as below:

```
   function moveEmailToFolder(){
    const Imap = require('imap');
    const imap = new Imap({
        user: config.email.user,
        password: config.email.password,
        host: config.email.host,
        port: 993,
        tls: {
                secureProtocol: "TLSv1_method"
        }
    });
    imap.connect();
    imap.once('ready', function(){
        imap.openBox("INBOX", false, function(err, box) {
            imap.search([ 'ALL' ], function(err, results) {
                let mail_no = "1:*";
                var f = imap.seq.fetch(mail_no, {
                    bodies: "",
                    struct: true,
                    markSeen: true
                });
                let all_emails = [];
                f.on("message", function(msg, seqno) {
                    let move_email_fn_calls = 0;
                    function move_email(uid){
                        imap.seq.move(uid, "processed", function(err) {
                            if( !err ){
                                console.log(uid+": move success");
                            } else if( err && move_email_fn_calls < 3 ){
                                move_email_fn_calls++;
                                move_email(uid);
                                console.log(uid+": " + err);
                            } else if( err && move_email_fn_calls >= 3){
                                console.log(uid+": Unable to move");
                            }
                            console.log(move_email_fn_calls);
                        });
                    } 
                    move_email(seqno);
                });
                f.once("error", function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
                f.once("end", function() {
                    imap.end();
                });
            });
        });
    });
    imap.once('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    imap.once('end', function() {
        console.log('Connection ended');
    });
}
```

Any help or advice is appreciated. 
Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

You are addressing the messages using sequence numbers while modifying the mailbox, which invalidates the sequence numbers.

Sequence numbers change. 4 means "the fourth message in the mailbox *right now*". If you move the second message elsewhere, the message that used to have number 4 now has number 3.

You have two options. First, you can use UIDs, which will work because UIDs are *u*nique *id*entifiers. Just delete both instances of `.seq`. Second, you can move all the messages using one command instead of looping and issuing an unholy number of single-message moves. `imap.move(results, …`, one command, or `imap.seq.move(results, …` which works because then you only reference messages before the modification changes the sequence numbers.